# How to call Server side Public method in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following ways to call :

Using Page Methods

1)

```
function callBackMiscQuoteItems(val) {
    PageMethods.FillTowingMiscItemsGrid();
}

[WebMethod]

public static void BindControls() {
}
```

2) `<% BindControls(); %>`

but this 2 procedures are not working

anybody there to help me out ..

can we use JQuery to call or any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net call WebMethod from Javascript asyncronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158055/asp-net-call-webmethod-from-javascript-asyncronous) - take a look at this post.

About your code. Your webmethod is called `BindControls`, if it is not just an example, but you are calling `PageMethods.FillTowingMiscItemsGrid()` instead of `PageMethods.BindControls()`. Another possible problem: `PageMethods.FillTowingMiscItemsGrid()` this call will do nothing on client side. You must specify success callback function to do something on client side:

```
PageMethods.FillTowingMiscItemsGrid(function(response) {//do something})
```

Also, code like `<% BindControls(); %>` is executed on server and will not generate JS call by default.

[Here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx) is a small tutorial about how to use webmethods.