# Databind a stored procedure to a asp.net label

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a stored procedure that i would like to add to a label.. How do i do this please and what even do i need to strike ... i.e

```
 protected void label_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I have my data being pulled from a class ..

Data class

```
 public DataSet TotalPacked(int itemSeriesMasterId, DateTime shiftstart, DateTime shiftend)
        {
            object[] args = new object[3] {itemSeriesMasterId, shiftstart, shiftend};
            return CallSp(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), args) as DataSet;
        }
    }
}
```

Biz Class

```
 public DataTable GetTotalPacked(DateTime shiftStart, DateTime shiftEnd, int seriesMasterId)
        {
            using (DataManager dmgr = new DataManager())
            {
                dmgr.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductionKey"]);
                DataSet dset = dmgr.TotalPacked(seriesMasterId,shiftStart,shiftEnd);
                return CreatePackingStats(dset);
```

So how do i call the stored proc from the label? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to call a `Stored procedure` from the `label`?

Comment: because i need to show updated figures every 30 seconds called from the database...

Comment: if you want to display the data only to the `label` then it does not need to be called from the `label`. An `ajax` request with `setInterval()` is a better approach for that.

Comment: I was told to do it this way by my manager, i am a trainee you see lol. I dont know what i am doing lol

Comment: you can take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7158055/2417602) it might help in what you are trying to do.

Comment: not sure what all of that was doing to be fair. is there noway you can attach a stored proc to a label
?

Comment: @DanialCarey attaching a stored procedure is not possible but what you are trying can be achieved by alternate methods. if you want I can post an example of how to make it happen.

Comment: yes please. I have also come across that you can put the label into a formview and it will work?

Answer (score 0):

So, in order for a `label` to have data refreshed in every couple of seconds you can try that by creating `WebMethod` to get the data and then call that particular `WebMethod` via a `setInterval()` from javascript.

For More info about `WebMethods` [WebMethods via Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services) &
[Paramterized WebMethods](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-WebMethod-from-JavaScript-with-parameters-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

> **Code sample:**

So, for example, I have a method called `GetTime()` from which I have to fetch DateTime and display that on to `label` in my .aspx page with a span of every 5 seconds. In order to do that, I have to call the WebMethods from JavaScript(client side). So first, we add a `ScriptManager`(this you can either drag from the toolbar or can simply write) on your either calling page(.aspx) or on your master page(if you need it in other pages) with an option of `EnablePageMethods="true"`.

**ScriptManager**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Server Side**:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetTime()
    {
        return System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

And to bind it on the client side i have the label and have set the property of the lable `ClientIdMode="Static"` so, we can easily get the control in javascript:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltime" ClientIDMode="Static">time will be displayed here</asp:Label>
```

and here is the javascript function to call the `Webmethod`:

```
function getTime()
{
  PageMethods.GetTime(ongetTimePass, ongetTimefail);            
}
```

The `PageMethods` takes the methodname along with the parameters and the onSuccess() and onFailure function with an syntax as:
`PageMethods.<WebMethodName>(Paramter1,Paramter2....,OnSucess(),OnFailure())`.

If you happen to have `JQuery` library attached to your project you can call the function via ajax as:

```
function getTime()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "default.aspx/GetTime",
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: ongetTimePass,
            failure: ongetTimefail
        });

    }
```

And here is the `ongetTimePass()` and the `ongetTimefail()` function:

```
 function ongetTimePass(result)
 {
     //here we pass the result if the method has a success response.            
     document.getElementById('lbltime').innerHTML = result;
 }

 function ongetTimefail(error)
 {
     alert(error);
 }
```

And now to call it, we add it to the [load()](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-and-window-onload-difference) event of the page with an [setInterval()] function(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp):

```
window.onload = function () {
        var st = setInterval(getTime, 1000);
    };
```